# Cloudfront url synchronized with s3 path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I was using s3 for for my static websites, we had three websites/paths in s3:

- example.com
- example.com/website1
- example.com/website2

Website1 and Website2 were folders inside the bucket example.com as expected. But now we need https urls so we decided to go with aws cloudfront for the redirects. Cloudfront generated for example a url like this, https://123455678.cloudfront.net .

When I navigate to the url, it gets the example.com correctly, but when I try to put like https://123455678.cloudfront.net/website1 it seems like its not entering the /website1 path in the s3. So it gives me this error because it's not finding the index.html inside the /website1 path.

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>C5259E1658595A69</RequestId>
  <HostId>
     B1HYQsr0Xv4M1avKlJ3G8t0rkVfCvbOoJadxm5z1BwapblBeERm3c6Ni+jZWxB8FlXEaF6bUAik=
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

I guess I have to do something in the origins and behaviours of my cloudfront distribution, but I can't figure out what to do there...

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427661/subfolder-redirect-issue-with-static-website-hosting-using-s3-cloudfront-and-or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by changing the origin domain name in my cloudfront distribution to my s3 bucket endpoint, located in the properties of my bucket in Static Website Hosting area.

[image: s3_endpoint]

[image: origin_domain]

Saved, waited for cloudfront to use the updated changes and it worked. Also my Default Root Object is set to index.html .

Hope it helps someone =)