# AWS Cloudfront distribute multilingual angular apps

Tags: angular, internationalization, amazon-cloudfront

I have an Angular app which is store in a AWS S3 bucket and distributed by Cloudfront.

Now I want to distribute my app in multiple languages. I've already translated my angular app and for each language I have on build.

So my S3 bucket looks like this:

```
de
   /index.html
   /script.js
en
   /index.html
   /script.js
```

For each language I want to serve another app.

In Cloudfront I created  two Origins which points to Origin Path `/de` and `/en`

So my URL schema is like this:

```
<appname>.<mydomain>.com/:lang
```

But my problem is, I dont get the Error Pages to work with these specific  language folders.
I need these Error Response Handlers to deliver the angular app(s) when a 404 occurred (due to a reload)

Does anyone know how I can solve this? Or should i create one more subdomain for each language? So it looks like this:

```
<lang>.<appname>.<mydomain>.com
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've recently bumped into the same problem. My situation:

- I have an Angular 5 app
- I'm using i18n for 2 languages (en & fr)
- S3 for website hosting and Cloudfront for CDN & custom domain name/ssl certificate
- My default language is EN, so https://example.com redirects to https://example.com/en/
- When a user navigates directly to a route (eg https://example.com/en/product/1234), it should also work, irrespectively of the number of subfolders

Solution:

- **Create 2 separate deployments**, 1 for each language (en, fr). Git bash tends to replace the /en/ with a local folder, so make sure your index.html file contains the right base url

> ng build -prod -aot --base-href /en/ --i18nFile=src/locale/messages.en.xlf --i1nFormat=xlf --locale=en

- Deploy these into an /en/ and /fr/ folder at the root of your S3 bucket
- Create a new CloudFront distribution. Make sure to leave the *Default Root Object* empty!
- Add your bucket as an S3 origin (as you otherwise would).
- Now, create a new **Lambda function**, use Node 6.10. Important: select US-EAST-1, as this is the only region supported by Lambda@Edge. Code:

```html
const path = require('path')

exports.handler = (evt, ctx, cb) => {
  const { request } = evt.Records[0].cf

  if (!path.extname(request.uri)) {
      if (request.uri.startsWith('/fr'))
        request.uri = '/fr/index.html'
      else
        request.uri = '/en/index.html'
  }
  cb(null, request)
}
```

- Next: publish this version (in the Action dropdown)
- Copy the ARN of this version, and go back to CloudFront -> Behaviors -> Default Behavior
- Select *Origin Request* as Event Type in the Lambda Function Associations, and paste the ARN of the Lambda function.

Building Angular with the base path parameter will establish the right subdirectory for your Angular app. The rewrite will make sure that resource files will not be rewritten, but all your routes will be redirected to index.html

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Have you noticed any delays due to the lambda function? I've hoped there is a solution without one

Comment: No, I haven't noticed any delays. Besides, it only triggers on cache misses.

Comment: The deployment syntax has changed since Angular 6+ (using angular.json configuration), but the underlying method is still valid.

Comment: You're talking about redirections when this actually is URL rewriting. The user's address bar won't change. This also means that `GET /fruits` will be associated to `/fr/index.html` in S3, which is proably not what you want. You should probably test with `request.uri === '/fr' || request.uri.startsWith('/fr/')`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but also wanted automatic redirection to the closest language when going to

```
<mydomain>.com/
```

Using Dries Van Hansewijck's solution and npm's locale package you can had redirection with the following code:

```
const path = require('path');
const locale = require("locale");
const supportedLocales = new locale.Locales(['en', 'de']);
locale.Locale["default"] = new locale.Locales('de');

module.exports.pendixPortalI18n = (event, context, callback) => {
  const { request } = event.Records[0].cf;
  const locale = getBestLocale(request);
  if (!path.extname(request.uri)) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    if (request.uri.startsWith('/en')) {
      console.log('ENGLISH detected')
      request.uri = '/en/index.html';
    } else if (request.uri.startsWith('/de')) {
      console.log('GERMAN detected')
      request.uri = '/de/index.html';
    } else {
      console.log('Default matching locale is ' + locale);
      request.uri = `/${locale}/index.html`;
    }
  }
  callback(null, request)
};

function getBestLocale(request) {
  /* First we try to find the accept-language value */
  if (request && request.headers
    && request.headers['accept-language'] && request.headers['accept-language'].length > 0
    && request.headers['accept-language'][0].value) {
    const acceptLanguage = request.headers['accept-language'][0].value;
    const locales = new locale.Locales(acceptLanguage);
    const bestMatch = locales.best(supportedLocales);
    console.log("You asked for: " + JSON.stringify(acceptLanguage));
    console.log("We support: " + supportedLocales);
    console.log("Our default is: " + locale.Locale["default"]);
    console.log('best match is ' + bestMatch);
    return bestMatch;
  }
  return 'de';
}
```

Here we try to find the user's language in the supported language list. In order to do that you need to forward the accept-language header to the origin in cloudfront (in the behavior tab). If the user's language is not in the supported languages list we redirect to german.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is create a `index.html` file in root s3 folder, this file can determine the language and made the appropriate redirect:

index.html:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    const defaultLanguage = 'en';
    const userLanguageStorageKey = 'user-language';
    const supportedLanguage = ['es', 'en', 'fr']
    const userLanguage = localStorage.getItem(userLanguageStorageKey);
    const browserLanguage = navigator.language ? navigator.language.slice(0, 2) : defaultLanguage;

    if (userLanguage && supportedLanguage.includes(userLanguage)){
        window.location.replace(userLanguage);
    } else if ( (userLanguage && !supportedLanguage.includes(userLanguage)) || !supportedLanguage.includes(browserLanguage) ){
        localStorage.setItem(userLanguageStorageKey, defaultLanguage);
        window.location.replace(defaultLanguage);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem(userLanguageStorageKey, browserLanguage);
        window.location.replace(browserLanguage);
    }
</script>
```

This script use localStorage and navigator.language.
According to documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/languages
navigator.languages

> The Accept-Language HTTP header in every HTTP request from the user's browser uses the same value for the navigator.languages

and

> The value of navigator.language is the first element of the returned array

So we can use `navigator.language` to determinate the redirect.